# Hash function for noise generation

Tags: c#, hash, hashcode

I'm making value noise generator and I found that my current hash produces a kind of pattern in the image:

[image]

So I am looking for a better hash function less predictable/repeatable.

I'm using a hash instead of just random numbers because I want it to be deterministic. Given an (x, y) coordinates it should always produce the same result.

It would also be nice, but not mandatory if it's possible to scale the hash function to accept more parameters easily, like (x, y, z), or (x, y, z, t), instead of just two.

My current hash is:

```
public static class Hash
{
    public static float GetHash(int x)
    {
        x = x ^ 61 ^ (x >> 16);
        x += x << 3;
        x ^= x >> 4;
        x *= 0x27d4eb2d;
        x ^= x >> 15;
        return x / (float)int.MaxValue;
    }

    public static float GetHash(int x, int y) => GetHash((y << 8) + x);
}
```

I added the line `x / (float)int.MaxValue` because I want a float result from 0 to 1.

But I must admit that I just copy-paste it from somewhere. Bitwise operations (and hashes) are not my strength.

Comment: I used the FNV1a hash for noise generation and found the same issues with patterns showing up, but managed to turn it into what looks like white noise with some tricks. Wrote about this here: https://marcospereira.me/2022/05/10/a-simple-hash-for-perlin-noise/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original answer:
I would use a library like https://github.com/Auburns/FastNoise_CSharp 
Maybe you can learn from the source code that is in that FastNoise.cs file

Modified answer including code, hashing functions from referenced sources "Copyright(c) 2017 Jordan Peck"

```
private const int X_PRIME = 1619;
private const int Y_PRIME = 31337;
private const int Z_PRIME = 6971;
private const int W_PRIME = 1013;

private static int Hash2D(int seed, int x, int y)
{
    int hash = seed;
    hash ^= X_PRIME * x;
    hash ^= Y_PRIME * y;

    hash = hash * hash * hash * 60493;
    hash = (hash >> 13) ^ hash;

    return hash;
}

private static int Hash3D(int seed, int x, int y, int z)
{
    int hash = seed;
    hash ^= X_PRIME * x;
    hash ^= Y_PRIME * y;
    hash ^= Z_PRIME * z;

    hash = hash * hash * hash * 60493;
    hash = (hash >> 13) ^ hash;

    return hash;
}

private static int Hash4D(int seed, int x, int y, int z, int w)
{
    int hash = seed;
    hash ^= X_PRIME * x;
    hash ^= Y_PRIME * y;
    hash ^= Z_PRIME * z;
    hash ^= W_PRIME * w;

    hash = hash * hash * hash * 60493;
    hash = (hash >> 13) ^ hash;

    return hash;
}
```